# MonoGame physics with two non-rectangular Texture2Ds

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

In MonoGame, how would I handle collisions and physics between two non-rectangular Texture2Ds? Obviously, since this is a game, speed is crucial. What are my options?

Comment: First that comes to my mind is the [Farseer Physics Engine](https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/). You can define your bodies through polygons and [let the library handle physics and collision](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/48424/38920). Btw this question is rather broad, and not a very good fit for SO.

Comment: If your map is large, you'll need to do additional optimizations to achieve good performance, like using temporal coherence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one such example of algorithms.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15573/D-Polygon-Collision-Detection

There are examples littered all over the web.

Essentially you want to check a BIG space around your object and you don't do more accurate checking until objects are more likely to be colliding with one another.